# Assembly, writing a single byte from register to memory overwrites other bytes

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

In 64bit x86 assembly nasm, how can I move a single byte from the register into a memory location defined in section .data?

I understand that this works

```
global _main

section .data
quotient db 0x0, 0x0, 0x30, 0xa ; 3 digit + newline
remainder db 0x0, 0x0, 0x30, 0xa; 3 digit + newline

section .text

_main:
mov rax, 0x2000004
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, quotient
mov rdx, 8
syscall ; outputs 0 /newline 0 /newline as expected

exit:
mov rax, 0x2000001
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

Also I know you can set a single byte using a byte keyword

```
mov rbx, quotient ; move location of quotient into memory
mov [rbx], byte 0x31 ; change first byte to ascii '1'
```

this would output 1 0 /newline 0 /newline as expected

However suppose I want to set it as a register value

```
mov rbx, quotient ; move location of quotient into memory
mov r8, 0x31 ; set another register to ascii '1'
mov [rbx], r8 ; write the register value into memory
```

This does output 1 but it seems to overwrite every byte in memory after that so the newlines get removed.

My question is how can I write a single 'byte' from register into the memory location?

Comment: You may wish to see this: https://wiki.cdot.senecacollege.ca/wiki/X86_64_Register_and_Instruction_Quick_Start . In particular to move one byte you can do `mov [rbx], r8b`

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I'm guessing from the article for 64bit registers you are writing 8 bytes into memory everytime and to write a single byte suffix the register name with a b? However when I try to suffix a register like rcx with rcxb nasm is giving me symbol `rcxb' not defined, is this a problem with my assembler or do only numbered registers have this ability?

Comment: Correct. If the source is a 64-bit register then a full 64-bits of data will be written to the destination memory address overwriting the 7 extra bytes after the one byte you really wanted to write.

Comment: Ah I found another article from googling the suffix thing
http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs033/docs/guides/x64_cheatsheet.pdf
seems like with different registers the suffixes are different to pick different bytes out of them. So for rcx to pick the first byte becomes cl

Answer (score 6):

64 bit registers contain 8 bytes so writing a register into memory via

```
mov [rbx], r8
```

will move 8 bytes into the memory location starting at rbx

The table below shows how to write 1,2,4 bytes out of any register into memory

[image]

So for example writing one byte (byte 0) out of the r8 register would be

```
mov [rbx], r8b
```

one byte out of rax would be

```
mov [rbx], al
```

reference: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs033/docs/guides/x64_cheatsheet.pdf